# Is there a more direct keyboard shortcut to cascade windows?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, context-menu

**Windows:** 10
**Keyboard:** Windows - 104 - standard layout keyboard

When windows are displaying off-screen due to changing displays or display configurations, I have found that the best means to get them back to the visual display regions is through the Taskbar Context Menu item `Cascade windows`.

To see this quickly, right click on an open space in the taskbar to pull up the menu which has it.

I tend to do most things with the keyboard so I was attempting to find a shortcut/sequence for doing `Cascade windows`.

The only thing I have found so far that does it is this (long) sequence:

- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>: show desktop
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> thrice: in my case, the third tab gets me to the `Task View` taskbar item
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Menu</kbd>: brings up the `Task View`s "classic context menu", which just happens to be the same (?) as the Taskbar's "classic context menu"
- <kbd>D</kbd>: chooses the `Cascade windows` menu item from the context menu

I'm ok with creating a binding for this but prefer to have something that works out of the box that I don't have to setup with every new laptop/reinstall.

Comment: Are you sure that what you're describing is in Windows 11? AFAIK there is no "Cascade windows" option at all in Windows 11 (and the Taskbar context menu doesn't have any options besides Taskbar settings (and Task Manager in newer versions of Windows 11)

Comment: My mistake. Updating to Win-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to bind that functionality to any key. Example:

```
^+0::DllCall("CascadeWindows", "uInt",0, "Int",4, "Int",0, "Int",0, "Int",0)
```

Would bind it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

[Source](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/80580-how-to-programmatically-tile-cascade-windows/) and [CascadeWindows API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-cascadewindows)

Comment: This worked but I had to quote the unsigned/signed integer parameters ("uInt" and "Int")
I was hoping for an out-of-the-box Win10 solution, but I'll mark this as accepted for now.
Thanks Destroy666!

Comment: @JoshThies np. Just to confirm, did you use AHK 2? 1 shouldn't require quoting, not sure about that one.

Comment: I see. Yes, it was AHK 2; which apparently does require quoting, in the way you have now shown.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Alt+Tab to put the focus on the (currently offscreen) window that you want to move.
Alt+SpaceBar then M (to Move the current window).
Use the arrow keys to move the window back into view.
Press ENTER when done.

Comment: I have found that this doesn't always work in practice. Sometimes the window stubbornly refuses to actually move where I tell it to, even with the mouse.

Comment: I haven't tried doing this with the mouse, other than by mistake, and it didn't work all that well then.  With the arrow keys, you have to press ENTER when done; otherwise the whole thing gets canceled.

Comment: I tried with the mouse when keyboard method didn't work. I did realize about pressing enter but, I still find it just doesn't always work. Maybe it is important to note that Chrome is typically the window I am trying to get back but maybe that is irrelevant. Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried it here with Chrome, Windows 10, and it works as I described it.